# How to consume html value of rest web service response in angular js

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, web-services, ionic-framework

i am consuming the restful web service and i got value in the format of html div tag, how to handle it in angular js and display same one in the view part 
Here is the response

```
reponse : {
         "results": [
            {
               "location": "<div class=\"ExternalClass5F47052A5E8540409190A07B0D2A376F\"><p>abcddd<\/p><\/div>",
               "Status": "0",
               "Comments": null,


            },
            {
               "location": "<div class=\"ExternalClass7013B125F9C148559C1DF779BDF05553\">xyzz<\/div>",
               "Status": "0",
               "Comments": null,

            }
         ]
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Ng-bind-html](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngSanitize/service/$sanitize) something like

```
<div ng-bind-html="yourhtmlresponse"></div>
```

[Here is working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/cb09agce/)

Comment: don't forget to include ng-santize